# How to check sizes of two (or more) dimensional array in C#?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I have:

```
double[,] table = new double[3,4];
```

How to check both sizes of that table? `table.Length` gives me `12` which is total number of elements in table.

Comment: What do you mean by size? Is it the count in the dimensions?

Comment: By size I meant number of columns and rows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `GetLength` method.

So `table.GetLength(0)` will return 3 and `table.GetLength(1)` will return 4.

The parameter for `GetLength` is the zero-based dimension of the array you want to know the length of.

Answer (score 5):

`Table.GetLength(0);` gives you 3

`Table.GetLength(1);` gives you 4

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

GetLength?

[ref](http://dotnetperls.com/multidimensional-array)

Comment: telling of coz, see the ref for the full example. i admit i am lazy :)